# Use same elasticsearch cluster for both test and production

Tags: elasticsearch

I am running a small website. And to save cost I would like to use the same elasticsearch cluster for both `test` and `production` traffic.

I have two indexes called `work` and `job`. I can create it using:

```
POST /prod/work
```

for production work.

But then I cannot use

```
POST /prod/job
```

to create one for production work:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Rejecting mapping update to [prod] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [job, work]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "Rejecting mapping update to [prod] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [job, work]"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the elasticsearch version 7.X where types are removed, please refer [removal of types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html) for more info, hence you can't create index like `/prod/work`, where `work` will act like a type, and elasticsearch already creates a implicit type called `_doc`, hence complain about more than 1 mapping type in exception.